# Android Newly Taken Photo from custom camera does not appear in gallery (media store)

Tags: android, camera, gallery, android-mediascanner

1. in my app, i initially load all the images from the gallery, i.e. (MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
2. user can take picture via my app, but i have a custom camera, i.e. i do not use default phone camera to take pictures, i have my own surface view, i deal with Camera object directly, and handle the camera picture. and i save this image in a custom folder.
3. i want the newly taken picture to appear in my gallery once user returns to my app

problem:
the newly taken picture does not appear in the cursor i loaded with MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI

the problem is gone only when i reinstall the app and force a rescan.

how do i fix this? i want every picture that was immediately taken will appear in my cursor?

i have done some researhc, but don't tell me the contentvalues with the startactivity solution like below

```
 startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

this does not work, because again, i have my own camera, i am not using the default camera activity from the phone

i also tried

```
 getContentResolver().notifyChange(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null);
```

this does not work either

can someone please help?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need to send an broadcast "ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE" so that the mediascanner can scan for the image you saved.

```
 Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
 mediaScanIntent.setData(uri);
 sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
```

just set the uri of the the newly created image. :)

Comment: Where do you need to add that? Just before the :

Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI

???

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are true, you need to provide the newly created file to the MediaStore.

[MediaScannerConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection.html) will help you.

> MediaScannerConnection provides a way for applications to pass a newly
>   created or downloaded media file to the media scanner service. The
>   media scanner service will read metadata from the file and add the
>   file to the media content provider. The MediaScannerConnectionClient
>   provides an interface for the media scanner service to return the Uri
>   for a newly scanned file to the client of the MediaScannerConnection
>   class.

Answer (score 0):

This works for now:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT){

   sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.parse("file://" + outPath)));

}else{                      

   sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://" + outPath)));

}
```