# Android camera Intent not saving in gallery

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent

I am creating a simple application which takes pictures using the camera intent. It works and the pictures are being saved in : storage/emulated/sd/pictures/my_folder .
The problem is that I can't see those pictures from the Android Gallery app.

I saw different posts about but I couldn't find an answer.
How can I watch the pictures?

Thanks

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18374140/android-newly-taken-photo-from-custom-camera-does-not-appear-in-gallery-media-s

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Wow! I couldn't expect a best answer!! It worked!! 
There are so many posts about that I couldn't find the most useful!

Thanks a lot ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to send an broadcast "ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE" so that the mediascanner can scan for the image you saved.

```
 Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
 mediaScanIntent.setData(uri);
 sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
```

just set the uri of the the newly created image. :)

[Click to view Source :)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18374140/android-newly-taken-photo-from-custom-camera-does-not-appear-in-gallery-media-s)